# Are object properties recreated for each instance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose you have

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
     return this;
  }
}

Foo.modes = {
 ModeA : 0,
 ModeB : 1
}
```

Will Foo.modes be created for each instance of Foo? How can this be shown to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an instance property created in the constructor, it's a static (class) property, so no. It will only be created once -- when the object literal is declared -- and assigned to the class constructor. Any instance of the class will have access, but no copies will be made.

To create an object for each instance of the class, you can either make a copy or a new object, and assign it to a property on `this`:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this.modes = {
      ModeA : 0,
      ModeB : 1
    }
  }
}
```

To create an object for the class, you should assign to the constructor, like you're doing now. If you take a look at Babel's output for static methods, you can see how this works. The ES6 code:

```
class Foo {
  static bar() { }
  baz() { }
}
```

will produce the ES5:

```
var Foo = function () {
  function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
  }

  Foo.bar = function bar() {};

  Foo.prototype.baz = function baz() {};

  return Foo;
}();
```

Properties assigned to the constructor's prototype will be "part of" the instance, while properties assigned directly to the constructor will be part of the class.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is this also true for `static` functions using `es2015` ? (only created once)

Comment: @BarryBones41 I added some more info on how that works, including the es5 output to show exactly what it desugars into.